# Why we need CPU registers with pipeline?

Tags: cpu, cpu-pipelines

I understand how CPUs work in general in RiscV, but things got a little complicated with pipeline and I don't get it why we need registers at all. For example, let's look at:

[image]

When the ALU's input was Reg File's output before adding support to pipeline, so what has changed now?

We can still do that same as when the clock ticks the Reg File still has the old values, so we can do the reading/use of old values at start of clock and update/change them near the end of the clock (which really happens) so no problems at all and no need for those registers...

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking what pipelining is good for? Or why data can by-pass the ALU, i. e. move directly from the ID/EX register to EX/MEM?

Comment: I'm asking why we need those blue parts in pipeline @idmean

Comment: The blue parts are latches (flip-flops) to temporarily store the data of one pipeline stage until the clock ticks and the data can be processed in the next stage. It wouldn't be possible to feed the next instruction into the pipeline if the circuit was purely combinatorial. Maybe watching this lecture will help you understand this better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Hj48Q_HCQY&list=PL5Q2soXY2Zi_uej3aY39YB5pfW4SJ7LlN&index=15